# GitHub vie Blue Ocean Agent: Invalid username or password

Tags: jenkins, github, credentials, jenkins-blueocean, github-enterprise

The line I googled was:

```
remote: Invalid username or password.
```

to back track a little bit:

I created a pipeline using Blue Ocean on Jenkins to run something stored on our GitHub Enterprise. Our internal enterprise is behind an http connection (not https or ssh). An API token helps the jenkins master to interact with github successfully including fetching and pushing pipelines to the repo.

When it comes to execution the jobs are forwarded to an Agent. That Agent attempts to connect to the given address just like the master but instead of successfully fetching the content it gets the message:

```
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
```

What I want to figure out is how the token gets from the master to the agent and why that is not working in my case.

While googeling I found the symptom a couple of times - none seem to apply to my case.

What I think is happening is that the node is using two factor instead of tokens, then again the GIT_ASKPASS seems to generate the token - in which case I do not know why the token would work for the master but not for the agent.

Here is the blue ocean log - slightly changed for anonymity.

```
Cloning the remote Git repository
Cloning with configured refspecs honoured and without tags
Cloning repository http://github.mycompany.de/myorg/myrepo.git
 > git init C:\jenkins\nodes\guinode\workspace\myrepo_master-CFRRXMXQEUULVB4YKQOFGB65CQNC4U5VJKTARN2A6TSBK5PBATBA # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from http://github.mycompany.de/myorg/myrepo.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials GitHub Enterprise Access Token
Setting http proxy: con-ffm-asg-01.mycompany.de:8080
 > git fetch --no-tags --progress http://github.mycompany.de/myorg/myrepo.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --no-tags --progress http://github.mycompany.de/myorg/myrepo.git +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'http://github.mycompany.de/myorg/myrepo.git/'
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2002)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1721)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:405)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:614)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:207)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:53)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:358)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:98)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from myagent.auto.mycompanywan.com/12.13.14.15:58671
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1693)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:310)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:908)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1146)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1186)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:113)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:85)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:75)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1$1.call(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at hudson.security.ACL.impersonate(ACL.java:260)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution$1.run(AbstractSynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:44)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
```

On the agent machine I can see the folders being created so the execution definitely happens on the agent side.

My core question is what is happening with my token and what needs to happen so that the agent machine can connect to our enterprise github.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correlation is not causation but I activated `Enable Agent → Master Access Control` in `Jenkins -> Configure Global Security` and the SCM step was successful now.

EDIT: I played around with credentials, deleted some and recreated a token. After that the error appeared again. Unchecking that option, hitting apply followed by checking that option and hitting apply repaired this problem for me.